# Ubuntu 22.04.1 Libreoffice 7.3.7.2 update to 7.5

Tags: libreoffice

Ubuntu 22.04.1 installed **LibreOffice 7.3.7.2**
What are the latest means of **updating to LibreOffice 7.5**?
I would appreciate answers **using snap**.
There are inaccurate answers many years old which IMHO should be archived for those who want to delve!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to discover the current versions available of the LibreOffice snap:

`snap info libreoffice`

Let's try it...

```
$ snap info libreoffice
name:      libreoffice
summary:   LibreOffice is a free and open source office suite
publisher: Canonical✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/libreoffice
contact:   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bugs?field.tag=snap
license:   MPL-2.0
description: |
  LibreOffice is a free and open source office suite, developed by The
  Document Foundation. The LibreOffice suite comprises programs for word
  processing, the creation and editing of spreadsheets, slideshows, diagrams
  and drawings, working with databases, and composing mathematical formulae.
snap-id: CpUkI0qPIIBVRsjy49adNq4D6Ra72y4v
channels:
  latest/stable:    7.4.5.1 2023-01-27 (265) 964MB -
  latest/candidate: 7.4.5.1 2023-01-27 (265) 964MB -
  latest/beta:      7.4.5.1 2023-01-26 (265) 964MB -
  latest/edge:      ↑
```

You can see that --as of the time of this writing-- Libreoffice 7.5 is not yet available using a snap.

As that release is only two days old, such is to be expected. Be patient, and version 7.5 will appear soon.

Comment: Not snap specific but, … 7.5 has been just added to flatpack the day before yesterday https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.libreoffice.LibreOffice

Comment: One would assume that all means of updating/installing LO are available when a new version is announced. Was there not an update automatically offered when one looked under Help?

Comment: One's assumption would be invalid simply because LibreOffice developers are not the authors of the snap package.

Comment: how do you install any of those version?

Comment: @Hossein try the search box at the top of the page, or open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get 7.5 now by using candidate or beta versions but they may not be stable.
sudo snap refresh libreoffice --candidate
or
sudo snap refresh libreoffice --beta